# cannot import rpy2.robjects but can import rpy2

Tags: python, r, import, cgi, rpy2

I developed a web tool by python, cgi, rpy2 and R, it works well on my personal computer.

So I am tryig to set it up on the server. The versions of the software I used on the server are shown below.

And I test rpy2 in command line, it works well. However, rpy2.robjects can not be imported when I run the web tool.  It returns the following error:

```
Error in .Call("R_isMethodsDispatchOn", onOff, P...aseenv.get("show")
LookupError: 'show' not found
```

What's more surprising is that I can import rpy2.  Dose any one has similar experience?

```
System: CentOS release 5.7
Python version: 2.7.8, 
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10), 
rpy2 version: 2.4.3
```

Thanks

Comment: for the same version of libraries use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and run on server `pip install -r requirement.txt`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I specify the R home directory by your command. There are difference version of R on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rpy2 works in console, but cannot be imported by website ( with error "R\_isMethodsDispatchOn")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051667/rpy2-works-in-console-but-cannot-be-imported-by-website-with-error-r-ismetho)