# Can import rpy2 but not rpy2.objects on university cluster

Tags: python, r, cluster-computing, rpy2

I realize this question is a bit related to previous questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051667/rpy2-works-in-console-but-cannot-be-imported-by-website-with-error-r-ismetho)), but I think they were getting different errors, and at any rate, I'm afraid I'm such a scrub with these sorts of environment issues that I may need some hand-holding...

Anyway, as the title says, I am trying to run a python 3.5 script that imports from rpy2.objects. I have gotten this to work on my local machine, and now I am trying to get it to work on my university cluster. This is the error:

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/drrichie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/home/drrichie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface_lib import openrlib
  File "/home/drrichie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py", line 44, in <module>
    rlib = _dlopen_rlib(R_HOME)
  File "/home/drrichie/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface_lib/openrlib.py", line 37, in _dlopen_rlib
    rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)
OSError: cannot load library '/cm/shared/apps/R/3.5.2/lib/libR.so': /cm/shared/apps/R/3.5.2/lib/libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I *can* successfully import rpy2:

```
>>> import rpy2
>>> rpy2.__version__
'3.3.0'
```

Some version information:

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 22:29:32) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
```

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I also loaded both of these modules at the command line first, with: `module load python/anaconda/3.5` and `module load R/3.5.2`.

I'm on the University of Pennsylvania GPC (more info [here](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/computing/gpc)), if that makes a difference. (Apologies if this is the sort of thing I should go to the GPC managers about.)

Comment: The *Anaconda, Inc.* line suggests you are running Python in the conda virtualenv which does not see machine OS environment (where possibly your R installation sits). Try an OS level (non-conda) Python install and run of `rpy2`. Alternatively, install R in Anaconda.

Comment: The cluster environment doesn't seem to allow me to do any `conda install`. I also ran into problems with trying to install and use rpy2 in the base install of Python. I think I'm just going to try to run this on my local machine with parallel processing. Should be fine. Thanks for your time and help....